# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n y_n|^p\leq\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n |^p\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}| y_n|^p\right)$ for $1<p<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Suppose that $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and  $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be in  $\ell_p$ for any  $1<p<\infty$

prove that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n y_n|^p\leq\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n |^p\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}| y_n|^p\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w=x/\|x\|_p$. Then $\|w\|_p=1$, and $|w_n|\leq1$ for all $n$. We have
$$
\sum_n|x_ny_n|^p=\|x\|_p^p\,\sum_n|w_ny_n|^p\leq\|x\|_p^p\sum_n|y_n|^p=\Big(\sum_n|x_n|^p\Big)\Big(\sum_n|y_n|^p\Big).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I very much like this solution

Comment: Martin Argerami $w_n=x_n/\|x\|_p$ is correct?

Comment: Yep. $\ \ \ \ $